# Flatness of certain $R \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, flatness, involutions, jacobian-conjecture

The two-dimensional [Jacobian Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture) over $\mathbb{C}$ says the following:
Let $p,q \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ satisfy $\operatorname{Jac}(p,q):=p_xq_y-p_yq_x \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.
Then $\mathbb{C}[p,q]=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Let $\beta: \mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be the following involution (= automorphism of order two):
$x \mapsto x, y \mapsto -y$.

Then we can write: $p=s_1+k_1$ and $q=s_2+k_2$, where $s_1,s_2$ are symmetric w.r.t. $\beta$ and $k_1,k_2$ are skew-symmetric w.r.t. $\beta$.

It is well-know and was proved in several ways that $\mathbb{C}[p,q] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module).

> **Question.** Is $\mathbb{C}[s_1,k_1,s_2,k_2] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ flat?

I am not sure if one of the known proofs for flatness of $\mathbb{C}[p,q] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ can be adjusted here.

I have also asked the above question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060846/a-related-question-to-the-jacobian-conjecture).

Any hints and comments are welcome! Thank you.

---

**Edit:** The one-dimensional case does not seem to help solve my above question, since if $f: \mathbb{C}[x] \to \mathbb{C}[x]$, $x \mapsto p$, has an invertible Jacobian $p_x \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, then $p=\lambda x + \mu$, for some $0 \neq \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}$. Then, $s_1=\mu, k_1=\lambda x$ ($\beta: x \mapsto -x$), so
$\mathbb{C}[s_1,k_1]=\mathbb{C}[x] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x]$ is flat.

If we do not require an invertible Jacobian, then of course there are counterexamples, the easiest: $p=x^2+x^3$, so $s_1=x^2, k_1=x^3$, and then
$\mathbb{C}[s_1,k_1]=\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x]$ is not flat.

Comment: Isn't it true that the 2-dimensional Jacobian conjecture implies the full Jacobian conjecture?

Comment: If I am not wrong, no, the $2$-dimensional JC does not imply the generalized JC (= $n$-dimensional JC, for all $n$); at least I have not seen such an implication. But if for a fixed $M$, the $M$-dimensional JC holds, then it holds for all $m \leq M$.

Comment: @dodd: not that I know.

Comment: Yes, I meant old results by  Gary Meisters, but my recollection was wrong.

Comment: @dodd, thank you very much for trying to help (I will try to find relevant results of Meisters). If you have any ideas about the above question-- you are welcome!

Comment: http://www.math.unl.edu/~gmeisters1/

Comment: @dodd, thank you!